# Add a link to the Module list page

Tags: 7, users, theming

In a Module list page (`admin/modules`) , We could see help, permission or configure links in Operations column. and also [Module Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/module_filter) customize it as a dropdown for each module listed.

Now I need to create a **new link** in that operations for every module installed. How should I do it?

I think I should go with `hook_page_alter()` but don't know how to start with since the $page array of `admin/modules` page is too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think not just form_alter makes this happen, "**theme**" too plays a game here. When you look into coder review Module file, you could find that.

Code Review which is a submodule of [Coder Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/coder) also adds a link to the `system_modules` form.

```
function coder_review_form_system_modules_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (!user_access('view code review') || isset($form['confirm'])) {
    return;
  }

  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'coder_review');
  $form['#attached']['css'][] = "$path/coder_review.css";
  foreach ($form['modules'] as $package_name => &$package) {
    if ($package_name[0] != '#') {
      foreach ($package as $module_name => &$module) {
        if ($module_name[0] != '#') {
          $module['links']['coder_review'] = array(
            '#type' => 'link',
            '#title' => t('Code review'),
            '#href' => "admin/config/development/coder/review/$module_name",
            '#options' => array('attributes' => array('class' => array('module-link', 'module-link-coder-review'), 'title' => t('Coder review'))),
          );
          $package['#theme'] = 'coder_review_modules_fieldset';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There is a particular line in this code that needs to be noted :

```
$package['#theme'] = 'coder_review_modules_fieldset';
```

This might be the reason your not able to get the link.

Function `theme_coder_review_modules_fieldset()` is implemented in *coder_review.admin.inc* file. In its comment block you could also find something like this

```
/**
 * Returns HTML for the modules form.
 *
 * This was copied from theme_system_modules_fieldset() and modified to handle
 * additional links.
 *
 * @param array $variables
 *   An associative array containing the key:
 *   - form: A render element representing the form.
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 *
 * @todo Create an issue for this and get this function into D8.
 */
```

Answer (score 2):

The [system_modules()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.admin.inc/function/system_modules/7) form is the one that provides that module list.

You can form alter that in a custom module like so:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MODULE_NAME_form_system_modules_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Loop through the array of module packages.
  foreach (element_children($form['modules']) as $package) {
    // Loop through the array of module rows for each package.
    foreach (element_children($form['modules'][$package]) as $module_filename) {
      // Add an extra operation link for each module row.
      $form['modules'][$package][$module_filename]['links']['new_operation_link'] = array(
        '#type' => 'link',
        '#title' => t('Link text'),
        '#href' => 'link/url',
        '#options' => array(
          'attributes' => array(
            'class' => array('module-link', 'module-link-configure'),
            'title' => t('Link hover text'),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Note that you need to change MODULE_NAME to the name of your module and you have the change the link key, text, url, etc. to meet your requirements.

**[EDIT]**
I have now tested it and it works.
Here is a working example with the placeholder values changed to make a link to google.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MODULE_NAME_form_system_modules_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Loop through the array of module packages.
  foreach (element_children($form['modules']) as $package) {
    // Loop through the array of module rows for each package.
    foreach (element_children($form['modules'][$package]) as $module_filename) {
      // Add an extra operation link for each module row.
      $form['modules'][$package][$module_filename]['links']['google'] = array(
        '#type' => 'link',
        '#title' => t('Google'),
        '#href' => 'http://google.com',
        '#options' => array(
          'attributes' => array(
            'class' => array('module-link', 'module-link-google'),
            'title' => t('Go to google'),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

You can also use relative internal links instead of the external google link above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) I will try this. I also want to know a function which returns list of contrib modules only. module_list also returns core modules.

Comment: This function returns an error stating "Cannot use string offset as an array". I will look into it.

Comment: I am still trying to figure it out. Do you know why this happens. In the array returned by $form['modules'] the first element is '#tree' . May be this might be the reason

Comment: Oops sorry, I typed the code straight into my answer without actually testing it. I made a change that should fix it but I still haven't tested it. I will have a minute to properly test it shortly.

Comment: Thanks again. Now the error message has gone but still the link doesn't appear.

Comment: I just had a quick test and it works for me. For reference I added an example with placeholder values changed to something that actually works.

Comment: Am I missing something? I cleared cache. The hook is called but still I couldn't get those links I tried disabling Module Filter too. Let me check this function in some other instance.

Comment: Not sure. Here is a screenshot of mine (with module filter 7.x-2.x-dev). http://imgur.com/ROepDrJ If you want to put your code in pastebin or drupal.stackexchange chat or something I can see if I see any bugs. Do you have any errors in the log?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22702/discussion-between-alliswell-and-rooby).